# 1nch Protocole - How to convert ETH to another token using hardhat fork mainnet

Tags: solidity, ether, ethers.js, hardhat

I'm using hardhat and I forked the mainnet. I created a function to convert ETH to another token using the same logic of 1nch protocole (https://github.com/1inch/1inchProtocol)

```
function _oneSplitSwapEth(address _to, uint256 _amount, uint256 _minReturn,
        uint256[] memory _distribution) internal {
        // Setup contracts
        IERC20 _toIERC20 = IERC20(_to);
        IOneSplit _oneSplitContract = IOneSplit(ONE_SPLIT_ADDRESS); // 0xC586BeF4a0992C495Cf22e1aeEE4E446CECDee0E

        // Approve tokens
        _toIERC20.approve(ONE_SPLIT_ADDRESS, _amount);
        console.log("Token approved");
        // Swap tokens: give _from, get _to
        _oneSplitContract.swap(IERC20(msg.value), _toIERC20, _amount, _minReturn, _distribution,
            FLAGS);

        console.log("ETH swapped succesfully !");

        // Reset approval
        _toIERC20.approve(ONE_SPLIT_ADDRESS, 0);
    }
```

When I try to execute the function `oneSplitSwapEth` in the `deploy.js` :

```
await dynasetSwap.oneSplitSwapEth(DaiAddress, 1000000, 0, [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
```

I have this error : `Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'OneSplit: msg.value shoule be used only for ETH swap'`